# Netbeans - How to take out a Jpanel from JFrame and make it a class?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I originally made a complex GUI in JFrame Form by the form editor.
There are several Jpanels inside the frame.

Now I am thinking of reusing some of the JPanels in other JFrames.
I know it is possible to copy and paste the JPanel, but what I really want to do is factoring out the JPanel to make it a class. Is it possible to do it in Netbeans?

EDIT:
Thanks for the advices, it was really helpful, but not solving my problem.
I still need to factor out the panel. Say if I have a Panel with several child panels inside. (eg: tabbed panel) I would like to design each of the child panel separately instead of doing them all together in a single class. That's my understanding of OOP. I did not do it at the first place because I was not familiar with netbeans nor I was an good designer. Now I realize I need to reuse some of the child panels. Am I able to factor out the code for each panel and make it a class without redoing the work? I used GridbagLayout.

Comment: I assume you mean you've built the UI using the form editor?

Comment: @peeskillet I do not want to redo it from scratch. I want to factor out my JPanel from my JFrame

Comment: Create a new `JPanel` form, select all the fields on the previous panel and copy them and past them into the new form.  This won't guarantee that everything will be brought across (event handlers, required code), but should give you a start

Comment: Usually we don't use multiple JFrames in single application

Comment: @MadProgrammer The biggest pain is that I have to redo the layout... so there is no way to factor out a Component from a JFrame?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: Why would you have to "redo the layout?"

Comment: Set the layout of the new panel as the same as the panel, it should maintain the layout properties (depending on the layout)

Comment: @trashgod because it lost everything when I copy and paste the componets inside. I used Gridbag layout.

Comment: Right click on the new `JPanel` and set the desired layout; use the same properties as the used on the frame's content pane.